# how to skip rows in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Here is my sp codes. I want to select next different 6 rows from result of this sp. How can I do that?

```
SELECT  N.NewsId,
        N.HeadCaption,
        (SELECT Name FROM NewsCategory 
         WHERE NewsCategoryId = N.HeadLineCategoryId) Category,
        N.PicUrl,
        N.Creation,
        SUBSTRING((fnStripTags(N.Description)),1,75) AS ShortDescription
FROM    News N
INNER JOIN
        (SELECT  HeadlineCategoryID, MAX(NewsID) max_id
         FROM    News           
         GROUP   BY HeadlineCategoryID) N_ 
   ON N.HeadlineCategoryID = N_.HeadlineCategoryID AND
      N.NewsID = N_.max_id
ORDER BY N.ViewIndex DESC  
LIMIT 6;
```

Comment: like this, select . . . limit 6 offset 6, here offset means from which row number

Comment: @ArashM.Dehghani Can you write it as an answer. It works fine. Thank you.

Comment: it's really easy, just put "offset 6" at the end of your command, it will be like this "limit 6 offset 6"

Comment: I mean, I tried it and it works. I want to set my question answered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, Okay, just like this

```
SELECT  N.NewsId,
        N.HeadCaption,
        (SELECT Name FROM NewsCategory 
         WHERE NewsCategoryId = N.HeadLineCategoryId) Category,
        N.PicUrl,
        N.Creation,
        SUBSTRING((fnStripTags(N.Description)),1,75) AS ShortDescription
FROM    News N
INNER JOIN
        (SELECT  HeadlineCategoryID, MAX(NewsID) max_id
         FROM    News           
         GROUP   BY HeadlineCategoryID) N_ 
   ON N.HeadlineCategoryID = N_.HeadlineCategoryID AND
      N.NewsID = N_.max_id
ORDER BY N.ViewIndex DESC  
LIMIT 6 limit 6;
```

at the end of code, with "limit 6" you get the next 6 rows from table/source

Answer (score 0):

Try with SELECT DISTINCT instead of SELECT

Comment: I think he wants next 6 result, you are right, but here he is different I don't think he's pointing to duplicate rows :D

Answer (score 0):

Use the [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) function

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned
>   by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments,
>   which must both be nonnegative integer constants, With two arguments,
>   the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return,
>   and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return.